# Incomplete response returned using the Amadeus sandbox API with amadeus-php package in laravel Application

Tags: php, laravel, amadeus

I've started developing an API for personal development project using Amadeus using Laravel. I am using the sandbox self-service API postman collection which works fine giving me all the information. I have installed the amadeus-php package from composer in my laravel application but when trying to request for the same, I am not getting the expected response.

Here's the function definition in php (controller in laravel) that I am using to perform the request.

```
public function getFlightOffer(Request $request)
  {

    $request->validate([
      "originLocationCode" => "required|string",
      "destinationLocationCode" => "required|string",
      "adults" => "required|alpha_num",
      "departureDate" => "required|date",
    ]);

    $data = [
      "originLocationCode" => $request->originLocationCode,
      "destinationLocationCode" => $request->destinationLocationCode,
      "departureDate" => $request->departureDate,
      "adults" => $request->adults,
      "max" => $request->max,
    ];

    try {
      $amadeus = Amadeus::builder()->build();
      $ssl_path = base_path() . '/certificates/cacert.pem';
      $amadeus->getClient()->setSslCertificate($ssl_path);

      // Flight Offers Search GET
      $flightOffers = $amadeus->getShopping()->getFlightOffers()->get(
        $data
      );

      return response(["data" => $flightOffers], 200, ['Content-type' => 'Appliaction/JSON']);
    } catch (ResponseException $e) {
      print $e;
    }
  }
```

This doesn't seem to return the complete information, instead it just returns lastTicketingDateTime for the Flight Offers Search API endpoint.

`Request payload:`

```
originLocationCode:SYD
destinationLocationCode:BYK
departureDate:2023-06-05
returnDate:2023-06-19
adults:1
max:5
```

`Response Data:`

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "lastTicketingDateTime": "2023-06-05"
        },
        {
            "lastTicketingDateTime": "2023-05-31"
        },
        {
            "lastTicketingDateTime": "2023-05-31"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, when using the official Postman collection from Amadeus, I am getting appropriate response from the Flight Offers Search API endpoint according to their APi specification.
Is my code doing anything wrong, or there is problem in the package itself?

Comment: You're running your request through `->validate()`, but after that You're accessing `$request` again. You should be accessing `$request->validated->(fields). Always, always, always `dd()` your output, to see what got stuck in your validator

Comment: This problem is specific to the amadeus-php package. The response is the same even without the validator. I have dd() the inputs, it has got no problems. The result from the       $flightOffers = $amadeus->getShopping()->getFlightOffers()->get(
        $data
      );
is leaving out all the response data, and only providing these given data